# Avoiding a sort on an already clustered index for group by

Tags: postgresql, index, clustered-index, group-by

On a table `T` with two fields, `pid` and `did`, the following query results in a seq. scan followed by a sort on `pid`:

```
select count(did), pid 
from  T
group by pid
```

Here is the query plan:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=21566127.88..22326004.09 rows=987621 width=8)
->  Sort  (cost=21566127.88..21816127.88 rows=100000000 width=8)
    Sort Key: pid
     ->  Seq Scan on tc  (cost=0.00..1442478.00 rows=100000000 width=8)
```

However, the table already has clustered index on `pid`.

Why doesn't Postgres simply scan the table and compute the group by? Why does it need to sort on `pid` again?

How can I force Postgres to use the clustered index for the group by?

Comment: I didn't know pg had "clustered indexes" (but I don't know it well). Could you describe exactly what indexes you have defined, and how you clustered, to make sure everyone knows exactly what you have? (And sorry if I'm completely missing the point due to my lack of knowledge of Postgres - just ignore this comment then :-) )

Comment: @Mat you are completely right - you can cluster a table on an index but it is a one-time operation.

Comment: Also, please post the result of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` which shows the actual times and row numbers.  Until then I'll leave an answer which may become useless later.

Comment: I created clustered index using the following two commands:

Comment: @Mat At a guess, they're regular secondary indexes of the heap (one of which might be unique and/or a PK), with one of them having been used to `CLUSTER` the table. This does *not* create a clustered index.

Answer (score 3):

As you have no `WHERE` clause, you (the query, that is) must scan the whole table to be able to compute the aggregate.  Once it has all the data, it is much easier to sort them directly than to go to an index and match the rows and return them in order.  This latter would involve further I/O which is slow compared to operation in the memory.

*If* you were on PostgreSQL 9.2 (or above) *and* you had an index on `(pid, did)` then the optimizer *might* have chosen an index scan instead.

Comment: I think @Sandeep's question is a bit different: *why is there "Sort" step at all?* `pid` is already sorted. So, ideally, this particular query is a very simple one-pass algorithm: as you go through a particular `pid`, you count all `did`. Once you see a next `pid`, you are done with this group -- just output current count. Since original `pid` were sorted, your groups will be automatically sorted as well since they will be produced in the same sequence as original `pid`s.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the question.  The problem is, that the table is sorted on `pid` only when the `CLUSTER` operation finishes - all subsequent changes will introduce disorder, as Craig described in his answer.

Comment: I see. I think `proc sql` engine from `SAS` offers an excellent compromise: they have a user-specified `sortedby=pid` flag that notifies the query optimizer about data being already pre-sorted. (A user can lie about sorting but if the user lies and the data is not sorted then the query would return a run-time error upon finding the first out-of-order instance).

Answer (score 1):

(Elaborating on @dezso's answer, which should be accepted as correct in preference to this one):

> However, the table already has clustered index on pid.

No, it doesn't, because PostgreSQL (at least in 9.3 and below) does not have clustered indexes ("index-oriented tables" in the language of some other DB vendors). All tables in PostgreSQL are heaps with secondary indexes.

You can `CLUSTER` on an index to sort the heap according to the index, but it's a one-time thing. Pg doesn't attempt to maintain that ordering with subsequent updates/inserts, so it cannot rely on the table being in that order. See [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html):

> "When a table is `CLUSTER`ed, it is physically reordered based on the index information. Clustering is a one-time operation: when the table is subsequently updated, the changes are not clustered. That is, no attempt is made to store new or updated rows according to their index order."

The closest thing Pg offers to index-only tables is support for index-only scans over secondary indexes in 9.2 and above. If there was an index on `(pid, did)` *and* the visibility map was sufficiently solid (ie: not too high a churn rate, autovacuum running frequently enough) then Pg might choose to perform an [*index-only scan*](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans). It would fetch most of the data from the secondary index and only goes to the heap for a minority of rows where it needs to check visibility information.

So: Consider upgrading to 9.2 and creating an index on `(pid, did)`.

Comment: Both you and @dezso are both much better at Postgres than I will ever hope to be., and I'm not trying to contradict but nuance. I was under the impression that you could reorganize the table repeatedly with CLUSTER. This would be a maintenance nightmare, though. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-cluster.html

Comment: @swasheck Sure you can; I think "one time" is meant as "not ongoing" rather than "only ever once". The point is that under update/insert/delete load it doesn't *stay* clustered.